# Dataframe text column split and place values under the right new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I need to transform this dataframe

```
data = {'CODES': ['ABC=V; XZE=6,0; FYK=5,0',
                  'RTK=6,0;XZE=6,0',
                  'FYK=5,0; RTK=6,0;ABC=V,'],
        'CUSTOMER': ['CUSTOMER1','CUSTOMER2,','CUSTOMER3',]
        }

CUSTOMERCODES = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

into this

```
data2 = {'ABC': ['V',np.NaN,'V'],
         'XZE': [6.0,6.0, np.NaN],
         'FYK': [5.0,np.NaN, 5.0],
         'RTK': [np.NaN,6.0, 6.0],
        'CUSTOMER': ['CUSTOMER1','CUSTOMER2,','CUSTOMER3']
        }

CUSTOMERCODES2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

How can i split the codes column and put the corresponding values under the right columns? (and convert text values into numeric)

Comment: I doubt that such as data restructuring can be done with any function internally, you will need to write some code to iterate over `data['CODES']` and perform required modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Olvin Roght, I am also note aware of any `pandas` functionality that can achieve this (doesn't mean there isn't one). But I think you can just iterate over the exploded series and assign each value-pair to an empty data frame for the exact index position. See the following code that does this for your example:

```py
data = {'CODES': ['ABC=V; XZE=6,0; FYK=5,0',
                  'RTK=6,0;XZE=6,0',
                  'FYK=5,0; RTK=6,0;ABC=V,'],
        'CUSTOMER': ['CUSTOMER1','CUSTOMER2,','CUSTOMER3',]
        }

CUSTOMERCODES = pd.DataFrame(data)

ser = CUSTOMERCODES['CODES'].str.split(";").explode()

CUSTOMERCODES2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i, v in zip(ser.index, ser.to_list()):
    CUSTOMERCODES2.loc[i, v.split("=")[0].strip()] = v.split("=")[1].strip().replace(",", "")
    
pd.concat([CUSTOMERCODES2, CUSTOMERCODES.drop(columns=['CODES'])], axis=1)

-------------------------------
    ABC XZE FYK RTK CUSTOMER
0   V   60  50  NaN CUSTOMER1
1   NaN 60  NaN 60  CUSTOMER2,
2   V   NaN 50  60  CUSTOMER3
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
col = ['CUSTOMER'] #creating list to assign the column names
val = {} #

for i,j in enumerate(CUSTOMERCODES.CODES):
    val[CUSTOMERCODES.CUSTOMER[i]]= {}
    for d in j.split(';'):
        col.append(d.split('=')[0].replace(' ',''))
        val[CUSTOMERCODES.CUSTOMER[i]][d.split('=')[0].replace(' ','')] = d.split('=')[1].replace(' ','')

col = list(set(col)) #to get the unique values
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=col) #create empty df with column names

for Cus, level2_dict in val.items():
    data.loc[len(data.index), 'CUSTOMER'] = Cus.replace(',','')
    for j in level2_dict:
        data.loc[data.loc[data['CUSTOMER'] == Cus.replace(',','')].index, j] = level2_dict.get(j)
        
data
```

Output:

```
    CUSTOMER    FYK XZE ABC RTK
0   CUSTOMER1   5,0 6,0 V   NaN
1   CUSTOMER2   NaN 6,0 NaN 6,0
2   CUSTOMER3   5,0 NaN V,  6,0
```